# Ejecutar Insert a tabla dentro de bucle con PDO

Tags: php, pdo, php5

Envío el año a mi clase y quiero insertar registros de la forma **AAAAMM** (*integer*)
El **MM** es de la forma 01, 02.... 11, 12.
Pero no ejecuta la clase. Muestra error en el *Insert*.

```
public function InsertarMesesAnio($anio){
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $mes = str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $periodo = $anio.$mes;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tperiodo (periodo, estado)
        VALUES :periodo, 'P'";
}
$BD = new ConexionDB();
$sth = $BD->prepare($sql);          
$sth->bindParam(':anio', $anio, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
}
```

Comment: Realmente no entiendo **por qué usas un entero para almacenar una fecha**. Es un error que he visto varias veces y no entiendo a qué se debe el que muchos programadores usen **el tipo de dato equivocado** en casos como estos. Si eso es una fecha ¿por qué lo guardas como un entero? Tanto PHP como MySQL tienen funciones para convertir, formatear, extrar períodos, hacer cálculos, diferencias y más cosas con fechas. Cuando tú declaras una fecha como entero pierdes todas esas ventajas y te expones a guardar datos con error como `201820` ¿cómo controlas que no existe un mes `20`?

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano, utilizan el campo período con ese formato para identificar a qué mes de qué año corresponde tal movimiento, indistintamente de la fecha de registro. Por eso solo se considera año y mes, el día no importa para este caso. Aunque existe la fecha del documento, supongo que de allí se podría obtener el período según lo que mencionas.

Comment: Es exactamente lo que quise decir en mi otro comentario. De un campo `DATETIME` puedes calcular cualquier cosa sin necesidad de fragmentarlo para almacenar de nuevo un dato que ya tienes, y además usando un tipo de dato que no es el más adecuado.

Comment: @A.Cedano Y qué función me permite hacer eso con un campo DATETIME?

Comment: Aunque en MySQL hay muchas funciones que nos permiten trabajar con períodos, intervalos, etc. quizá sea mejor hacerlo por programación (al menos eso pienso, para no cargar demasiado a la base de datos). En PHP cuentas con toda una clase [**`DateTime`**](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) que incorpora métodos para casi todo. Hay otra clase llamada [**`DatePeriod`**](http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateperiod.php) y una clase [**`DateInterval`**](http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php). Como ves, dudo mucho que haya algo que no puedas hacer con una fecha desde PHP.

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que es cierto, las tablas deben tener las fechas correspondientes pero en algún lugar hay que almacenar el período actual de trabajo (o período activo de trabajo). Y este es el caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes ya resuelta la función de generar los elementos a insertar, pero tienes errores puntuales

1. El parámetro tiene por nombre `periodo` en tu sentencia y en `bind` es `anio`, tendrás que decidir con cual te quedas.
2. Tienes un error de sintaxis para pasar el `VALUES()` , va entre paréntesis .
3. No veo la necesidad de tener una cadena que nunca cambiará en un `for`, esté `for` se podría utilizar para insertar los elementos , **después de** preparar la sentencia para solo asignar los valores generados.

**Posible Función Final**

```
    public function InsertarMesesAnio($anio){
      $BD = new ConexionDB();  
      $sql = "INSERT INTO tperiodo (periodo, estado)
            VALUES (:periodo, 'P')";
      //Preparamos la sentencia una sola vez
      $sth = $BD->prepare($sql); 
      for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
          $mes = str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
          $periodo = $anio.$mes;
          //Asignamos el valor generado al parámetro y ejecutamos la sentencia
          $sth->bindParam(':periodo', $periodo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
          $sth->execute();
      }
    }
```